# C++ function that returns value into switch statement

Tags: c++, function, switch-statement, do-while

Currently I have a working program, but am trying different things to see if they work. below is the code I am trying to get to work but having  a function that asks the user to make a selection. I want to return that value into my main function which will run a do while loop that includes a case. Originally I have it as an if else if statement, but want to cut that down if possible. Below is the code I am working with. When running the program it only returns the entire menu instead of running the function from the value that should be returned.

```
 {
        int choice;
        createEmptySeats();
        seatPrice();

        do {
            choice = menu();
            switch (choice)
            {
            case '1': 
                reserveSeat();
                break;
            case '2': 
                displayInfo();
                break;
            case '3': 
                DisplaySummary();
                break;
            case '4': 
                break;
            }
        }
        while (!seatFull());

        return 0;
    }


        int menu() 
        {
            int userSelection = -1;
            while (userSelection < 1 || userSelection > 4) 
            {
                cout << "Please Choose Option Below" << endl;
                cout << "1: Reserve Seat(s)"<<endl;
                cout << "2: Display Available Seats" << endl;
                cout << "3: Display Information:" << endl;
                cout << "4: Exit System" << endl;
                cin >> userSelection;
            }
            return userSelection;
        }
```

Comment: Typo? You need to add `break;` statements before each new `case` otherwise it will just fall through to the next `case`.

Comment: That is indeed the correct answer, unless the fallthrough behavior was what you intended.

Comment: If `userSelection = 0` then what will happen, Plus you forgot `break;` statement after each case. You may have a `default` case too.

Comment: I added the break after each case. I did forget that, but it still is not returning a function, but instead it is just giving me the menu over again.

Comment: @user3397512 : You will have to add `break;` after each case

Comment: I added the break; My int main () looks like this now. <code> int main()
{
 int choice;
 createEmptySeats();
 seatPrice();
 
 do {
  choice = menu();
  switch (choice)
  {
  case '1': 
   reserveSeat();
   break;
  case '2': 
   displayInfo();
   break;
  case '3': 
   DisplaySummary();
   break;
  case '4': 
   break;
  }
 }
 while (!seatFull());
   
 return 0;
} </code>

Comment: and then what happens?

Comment: it just returns the original menu. For instance upon loading it shows the menu. I hit one and instead of loading the function for reserveSeat() it loads menu() agai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:** You're missing `break;` in your switch statement for each of the cases, except case 4 (not sure if it's by design).

**Second:** Choice is `int`, your cases are `char`s.  Change one of them, so that both of them match.  You're never finding a match for your case, so you just keep on looping.

Comment: Noobacode. That is what I have now, but it is loading the menu over again. I am guessing the userSelection is not passing through, but not sure how to test that.

Comment: @user3397512 Loading which menu over again?  There are bunch of things that can go wrong, you may never return a true from your `seatFull()` function, so there's no way for us to know what's going on without seeing that code.

Comment: @user3397512 Well, you will keep on running that function while do{}while() keeps on running, the way you have it designed.  That loop will keep on running until your `seatFull()` returns true.

Comment: Sorry I did not post then entire code, just the part that was erroring out. My original statement was int main()
{
 createEmptySeats();
 seatPrice();

 while (!seatFull()) 
 {
  int ch = menu();
  if (ch == 1) 
  {
   reserveSeat();
  }
  else if (ch == 2) 
  {
   displayInfo();
  }
  else if(ch==3)
  {
   DisplaySummary();
  }
  else if(ch==0)
  {
   break;
  }
 }
 // system("pause");
 return 0;
}
I tried to just change to a switch statement.

Comment: @user3397512 look at my edit for explanation on what's going on.

Comment: It worked while I had it as just a while statement with while (!seatFull()), so I am not sure why it would not work now. I'snt the expression the same?

Comment: I do have the breaks in there now. I just didnt know if I should edit the first question with the new code or respond back on the comments. First time using this site.

Comment: @user3397512 yes, edit your question.

Comment: @user3397512 Read my edit for all the possible solutions.  Change it so that either your choice is `char`, or your cases are `int`s.

Comment: the char was the error. Fixed that and it works perfectly. Always the smallest thing. Thanks for all the help from everyone.

Comment: @user3397512 No problem, glad we could find a fix.

Answer (score 1):

choice is int, and you write char - '1', '2' in the case. Write as follows:

```
    choice = menu();
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1: 
        reserveSeat();
        break;
    case 2: 
        displayInfo();
        break;
    // ...
```

In your code you can come to `case '1'` when choice is an ASCII code of '1', i.e. 49. In your code it could never happen, so you stuck in the infinite loop with menu().